# Unpatch data of vision transformer

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model, vision-transformer

I have a patch_tensor with the shape: `torch.Size([2, 77, 256])` and I want to Unpatchify this to `(N,H,W,C)` or `(N,C,H,W)`. The original shape of image is (2,4,64,64).

For patch embedding, I am using the `PatchEmbed` from `timm` library:

```
hidden_size = 36 / in_channels = 4 / patch_size = 8 / input_size = 64
```

```
from timm.models.vision_transformer import PatchEmbed
PatchEmbed(input_size, patch_size, in_channels, hidden_size, bias=True)
```

The encoder block of transformer is similar to the vanilla transformer.

So after extracting patches using  `PatchEmbed`, the shape of the patched vector is :  `torch.Size([2, 64, 36])` .

This vector then goes through the Transformer's Encoder and the resulting vector shape is :

```
torch.Size([2, 77, 256])
```

From this point, I am not sure how to start unpatch this vector. Can you please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your image size before the patching step?

Comment: It is 64x64 with 4 channels. I am sending a vector in shape (2,4,64,64) to be patched.

Comment: With the PatchEmbed you are projecting the original image in an embedding space of resolution 8x8 and channel size 36 (flattened to (64x36) where each pixel comes from a patch of size 8. You cannot easily (if not lerarning some weights) reverse the operation.